# Want to replace windows 7 with Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I am looking to replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu 14.04 but my system configuration is:
Processor: Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N550 @ 1.50GHz
Installed Memory(RAM): 2.00 GB
System type: 32-Bit Operating System

please recommend me how will I get Ubuntu 14.04 in my system
Can you point to a site that can guide through the process

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Download Ubuntu 14.04.
Here is a link for that:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop.

Step 2: Create an ubuntu boot able USB, here are the steps :

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Step 3: Reboot your computer and boot from USB. To do that usually you will have to press F12
Here is a link on how to do that: 
http://lifehacker.com/5991848/how-to-boot-from-a-cd-or-usb-drive-on-any-pc

Step 4: Install ubuntu and enjoy its amazing features:
Here is a link on how to install it:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

**PS: Make sure you choose 32 bit.**

External References: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWUf45ZPAQM

Answer (score 0):

go to http://ubuntu.com download 32 bit version of the os ver 14.04 lts . burn it to disk or create a live usb key with (lili for windows) live linux key creator .boot it to your system and install it if you like it .

Answer (score 0):

[This will guide you in preparing how to prepare the Ubuntu installation.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) -   For both DVD install and USB install.  There are links to help decide which version is best for your PC Configuration.

[This will show you the common installation steps.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)  They should be followed exactly to answer any question you have along the way and prevent any errors from showing up.

Since you are going to replace Windows, it will be wise to make a backup of your important data that resides within the Windows partition. Remember, only 32 bit flavor can be supported on your PC.